# Cyberpanel: ext4 filesystem invalid superblock checksum

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digital-ocean, corruption, cyber-panel

We're using **DigitalOcean** and **CyberPanel**, with a Droplet of 25GB. We upgrade it to 60GB (the Digitalocean offer of 18$/month).

But we got an issue of 25/25GB disk is full after research we found that when we upgrade from 25GB to 60GB it wasn't done successfully so we passed the following command (as Digitalocean support recommended):

`growpart /dev/vda 1` then `resize2fs /dev/vda1`.

So I get this error now:
[image]

Know I can only run the recovery console on the recovery iOS.

Comand `lsblk`

it return:
[image]

We don't have any backup (yes it's a big mistake from our side) so anyone have any idea how can we can solve this issue without losing any Data? (We have 4 websites).